# WP Widget Select Box selections not displaying correctly on save

Tags: wordpress, select, widget

I am attempting to create a custom Wordpress Widget, that has a dropdown select  field. Everything works, however when I go back to the widget (for example to edit) the select dropdown always displays the top result instead of my selection. Now what can I do? Please help me.

```
public function form($three){
    ?>

        <div class="hut-widget-form">
            <label for="">Loop</label>
            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('loop') ?>" id="" class="widefat" > 
                <option  value="true" >True</option>
                <option  value="false">False</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    <?php   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check current selected/saved value ad set the selected item.

WordPress selected() function can be handy.

More Info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/selected/

I assume that selected value is fetched using "$this->get_field_name('loop')"

Modify You Code To This:

```
public function form($three){
    ?>

        <div class="hut-widget-form">
            <label for="">Loop</label>
            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('loop') ?>" id="" class="widefat" > 
                <option  value="true" <?php selected( $this->get_field_name('loop'), "true" ); ?>>True</option>
                <option  value="false"<?php selected( $this->get_field_name('loop'), "false" ); ?>>False</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    <?php   
}
```